# Progress View Missing when scroll to left/right swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiprogressview

i have collection view in horizontal position. user can download file, it display progress view, after download complete the progress view is fully filled with blue color but if I scroll the collection view until the file that already downloaded not visible, the progress view missing

here's my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: magazineCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! magazineCell

    cell.progressDownload.hidden = true //the progress bar
    cell.progressLabel.hidden = true //download percent
    cell.progressDownload.setProgress(0, animated: true)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.progressDownload.hidden = false
    cell.progressLabel.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating the progress? Are you using `UIProgressView`? I guess what happens is that you loose the reference to your progress view, but it's hard to tell since relevant code is missing.

Comment: What you did after completing the download process.

Answer (score 1):

When scrolling cells are recreated which hides your progress bar again, somehow you need manage to check if there is already downloading or not ,then set progress bar show/hidden and downloaded progress.